# Java RMI ConnectException when connecting to server. Different IP supplied in code than error message shows

Tags: java, exception, rmi

I'm running into a strange problem with my RMI application.
When I try to start a client program from another pc to try and connect to the server on my pc the client gives a ConnectException.

The exception says it is unable to connect to 192.168.152.1 which is strange because my code is the following:

Client:

```
public RMIController() throws RemoteException {
    super("rmi");
    this.registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry("192.168.178.111", 1099);
}
```

Server:

```
public RMIRegistry() throws RemoteException {
    this.registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);
}
```

When running the server I also give it the following command line argument:

> -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=192.168.178.111

Before I gave it this command line argument I did try the System.setProperty variant to this:

```
System.setProperty("java.rmi.server.hostname", "192.168.178.111");
```

That also gave no result.

I already looked up a couple of things and the problem is not the hosts file on either computer.
What could be the problem here?

EDIT:

After some searching I found out this is a typical multi-homed problem, this is a known issue:
http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4880793

Does anyone have a proper solution for this?

EDIT 2:

I found a solution for this. In the control panel in the network center I disabled every internet adapter apart from Wi-Fi. This is no official solution but it does the trick for now.

Comment: Is 192.168.152.1 mentioned in your hosts  file?

Comment: No, that's the strange thing, I looked at both of the hosts files and I couldn't find a single record. I also stepped a little further and performed a ping scan from the client computer to check if the host was available and it couldn't be reached. However this host was available on my own computer.

Comment: Well the basic issue is that [`hostname(2)`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/gethostname) or one of its friends is returning that IP address for some reason. I don't know why `java.rmi.server.hostname` doesn't fix it it but is actually a `hosts` or DNS configuration error: if you can fix that you're done.

Comment: Alright, that is strange. I also can't seem to access my modem/router by entering 192.168.178.1 in the browser. Maybe my router is malfunctioning. I'll go check on that.

Comment: It seems it is not my routers fault. I ran an ipconfig /all and I found that there is a VMWare network adapter called VMNet8 running on 192.168.152.1.

Comment: This enhancement request you cited isn't a bug or 'known issue'. It confirms what I've said above.